# How do you understand this phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Otherwise, I might think of John Milton when I think of California and the writer’s task. Milton devised that, after the Fall, the temperature in San Diego would remain at 75 degrees, but Adam and Eve’s relationship to a perfect winter day would be changed to one of goose bumps."

This is quoted from [Richard Rodriguez, Disappointment *CALIFORNIA MAGAZINE* 2006](https://alumni.berkeley.edu/california-magazine/january-february-2006-chinafornia/disappointment-0)

Maybe someone could put this sentence in another words? I honestly don't get the meaning of this phrase.

Comment: Which sentence? You quote two. Also, you don't really give us enough context. Further, I can't find any evidence that John Milton knew of San Diego.

Comment: Is this a taped speech?

Comment: This makes no sense unless you put it in context.  You didn't even link to the source.

Comment: When put in context, the author means exactly what he says.  All the words mean exactly what the dictionary says they mean. And it is completely incomprehensible. So if you honestly don't get the meaning, that is exactly right.

Comment: It is [here](https://alumni.berkeley.edu/california-magazine/january-february-2006-chinafornia/disappointment-0), for what it's worth :-(

Comment: John Milton was the author of *Paradise Lost*, a poem about the expulsion of Adam and Eve from the Garden of Eden. That's as far as I can get. That second line is complete gibberish as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is discussing how writers, such as John Steinbeck, have written about California.

He forms an analogue between the task of writing about California and the task that John Milton faced when writing about the Garden of Eden. The author develops a complex theme on the topic of expressing disappointment in a failed (or lost) paradise. The author assumes that the reader will be familiar with both *Paradise Lost* and *The Grapes of Wrath*.

The "gibberish" arises because the author is deliberately mixing California with Eden, placing San Diego in Eden, for example. Though Eden/California must be seen as perfect from the outside, for Adam and Eve there is only imperfections, symbolised by goosebumps.

This answer has already strayed to literary criticism.  The meaning of the paragraph is completely as written, there is no special grammar or specific English writing techniques employed.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer!